# How to change visual studio code output path color white to green. I am stuck, someone please help me with the setting?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can Someone please help me to change highlighted visual studio output path color?.I am unable to find the settings to change visual studio output path color only ,i want to change it to green. I am new in Visual Studio code.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that exactly but I can guide you to the proper area to find what you want. Visit the vscode api documentation, its under "Theme Color" here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color

Comment: why are you using a proportional font in the editor, you want to change the color of the command, this command is "typed" by the language extension on the terminal, maybe it is possible to configure it to send `ASCII Escape Sequences` to set/reset colors

Comment: Do you use code runner?